# How should client download resource from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm kinda new to AWS S3 - using EC2 (hosting web app) and S3 (storing resources) in the same AWS region, and assigned EC2 with an IAM role `s3access`, so EC2 can download from S3 easily.

The question is, how should a client download from S3? Apparently the client doesn't have `IAM role` or `Access Key` like EC2 does. Seems the client only have a `signedDownloadUrl` generated by `aws-sdk`, but it also requires access key.

So, should I make the bucket public then any client can download, or should I find some approach to supply the client with credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All objects by default are private. Only the object owner has permission to access these objects.

So if you want to share an object with someone you can

1. You can make it public or
2. You, the object owner can share objects with others by creating a **pre-signed URL**, using their own security credentials, to grant time-limited permission to download the objects.

For more details on pre-signed URLs refer [S3 Share Objects with PreSignedURL](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I guess the 'object owner' refers to the client who uploaded the object. But again, does a client has AWS credentials? I thought only EC2 and AWS account has credentials..

Comment: By object owner it means whoever uploads the object. If you have a program in EC2 that does it then from the same program you can generate the signed URLs